# Remove everything after 3rd . in Python

Tags: python

I have a string in my Python program. I'd like to strip everything after the third `.`. I've tried `strip()` and `split()` but not getting the expected output. How to do this?

Comment: an example input / output and your tested code would help answerers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
s = 'aaa.bbb.ccc.xxx.xxx.xxx'
stripped = '.'.join(s.split('.')[:3])
print(stripped)
```